# What's the recommended way to reset sharded counts on App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, count, memcached, google-cloud-datastore, sharding

App Engine docs suggest using sharding across several entities to implement a counter that is frequently updated. The number of such shards keeps increasing with increasing traffic. If at some point, the count needs to be reset to 0, what would be the most efficient way of achieving this:

- resetting the counts of all shards created so far to 0
- or expending these shards in a background deletion while fresh shards with new names replace them immediately?
- or some other approach?

Comment: You could consider a cross-group transaction to reset en-masse. The other option you suggest - switching to a new set of counters sounds reasonable too.

Comment: Change the counter name would be the easiest and cheapest option!